# Use same authorization policies for client and server in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

*This question is a follow-up from my `ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor` issue reported [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/12391).*

Using the current preview (6) for .NET Core 3.0, the `ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor` project template creates the following three projects:

- MyProject.Client (**.NET Standard 2.0**)
- MyProject.Server (**.NET Core 3.0**)
- MyProject.Shared (**.NET Standard 2.0**)

I want to enable authorization in my server project (to protect the endpoints), as well as in my client project (to dynamically show or hide views or parts of views).

For that use case I created the policies in the `MyProject.Shared` project, after which I could use them in the client project. However, they were not available in the server project.

**The problems:**

1. - .NET Core 3.0 authorization policies derive from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy` defined by the `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`.
   - .NET Standard 2.0 authorization policies derive from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationPolicy` defined by `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" [...] />`.
2. - The `AuthorizationPolicy` constructor requires a set of authentication schemes.
   - For .NET Core 3.0 those are defined in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants` defined by the `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`.
   - For .NET Standard 2.0 those are defined in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityConstants` defined by `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />`. However, this package won't be available in any higher version than `2.2.0`, as [Microsoft decided to discontinue certain packages](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/3756) with the .NET Core 3.0 release, and rather move those classes into the `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`.

**My questions:**
What is the correct way to use the **same** policies - without defining them twice for .NET Standard and .NET Core - in both the server and client project?

- Take the compability between the framework reference of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization (3.0.0)` for granted?
- Take the compability between the framework reference of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` and the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (2.2.0)` for granted?

---

**Edit:** In order to correctly setup the shared policies in the `MyProject.Shared` project, I have to reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity (2.2.0)` package - to include `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`.
However, this causes the build of `MyProject.Client` to fail:

```
2>Processing embedded resource linker descriptor: mscorlib.xml
2>Duplicate preserve in resource mscorlib.xml in mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e of System.Threading.WasmRuntime (All).  Duplicate uses (All)
2>Type Mono.ValueTuple has no fields to preserve
2>Type System.Reflection.Assembly has no fields to preserve
2>Fatal error in IL Linker
2>
2>Unhandled Exception: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Void System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission::Demand()' in assembly: 'System.Security.Permissions.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal System.Threading.Thread::get_CurrentPrincipal()
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
2>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
2>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run(ILogger customLogger)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Execute(String[] args, ILogger customLogger)
2>   at Mono.Linker.Driver.Main(String[] args)
```

Followed up by this cryptic error message:

```
\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\targets\Blazor.MonoRuntime.targets(439,5): error MSB3073: The command "dotnet "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.10.0-preview6.19303.4\build\netstandard1.0\../../tools/illink/illink.dll" -l none --disable-opt unreachablebodies --verbose --strip-security true --exclude-feature com --exclude-feature sre -v false -c link -u link -b true -d "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.10.0-preview6.19303.4\build\netstandard1.0\../../tools/mono/bcl/" -d "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.mono\0.10.0-preview6.19303.4\build\netstandard1.0\../../tools/mono/bcl/Facades/" -o "S:\git\hou-units\src\UNITS\UNITS.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker/" -x "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor.build\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\targets\BuiltInBclLinkerDescriptor.xml" -x "S:\git\hou-units\src\UNITS\UNITS.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\blazor\linker.descriptor.xml" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\jetbrains.annotations\2019.1.3\lib\netstandard2.0\JetBrains.Annotations.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.core\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.blazor\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.browser\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.cryptography.internal\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.cryptography.keyderivation\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.server.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.identity\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.metadata\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Metadata.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.abstractions\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.hosting.abstractions\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.identity.core\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.logging.abstractions\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.objectpool\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.options\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.primitives\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.extensions.webencoders\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\microsoft.jsinterop\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.JSInterop.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.net.http.headers\2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.win32.registry\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\mono.webassembly.interop\3.0.0-preview6.19304.6\lib\netstandard2.0\Mono.WebAssembly.Interop.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\12.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.buffers\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.componentmodel.annotations\4.6.0-preview6.19303.8\lib\netstandard2.0\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.memory\4.5.3\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.numerics.vectors\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.6.0-preview6.19303.8\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.accesscontrol\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.AccessControl.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.security.cryptography.cng\4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.cryptography.pkcs\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.cryptography.xml\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.permissions\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Permissions.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.security.principal.windows\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll" -a "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.text.encodings.web\4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.text.json\4.6.0-preview6.19303.8\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Json.dll" -a "C:\Users\Stefan\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.2\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll" -a "S:\git\hou-units\src\UNITS\UNITS.Shared\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\UNITS.Shared.dll" -a "S:\git\hou-units\src\UNITS\UNITS.Client\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\UNITS.Client.dll"" exited with code -532462766.
```

**Example project can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/Herdo/hou-units/tree/prototype-blazor/src/UNITS).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [*Chris Sainty's* recent article about policy-based authorization](https://chrissainty.com/securing-your-blazor-apps-configuring-policy-based-authorization-with-blazor/), the correct way I came up with was switching from typed policies to using the other overload, that allowed the configuration of the policy instead.

Instead of creating a class for every policy which require the `AuthenticationScheme` and using the `AuthorizationOptions.AddPolicy(string name, AuthorizationPolicy policy)` method, I implemented an extension method that calls `AuthorizationOptions.AddPolicy(string name, Action<AuthorizationPolicyBuilder> configurePolicy)` instead.

## Prerequisites

- Use the ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor template.
- In your shared project you have to reference the NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` with a version greater or equal to `3.0.0`.

## 1. Defining policies

In the shared project, create a class called `Policies`, where you define all your policies with configuration methods. The configuration methods should have the name of your policy - e.g.:

```cs
public static class Policies
{
    // This policy is internal and required for the extension method explained further below.
    // You CANNOT use this policy in your controllers or pages.
    internal static void PolicyConfigurationFailedFallback(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder)
        => builder.RequireAssertion(context => false);

    public static void TimeMustBeEvening(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder builder)
        => builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                  .RequireAssertion(context => DateTime.UtcNow.Hour >= 18);
}
```

## 2. Creating the extension method

This extension method automatically applies all **`public`** policies in your `Policies` class to the `AuthorizationOptions` from the `services.AddAuthorizationCore` method (see step #3):

```
public static class AuthorizationOptionsExtension
{
    public static void AddSharedPolicies(this AuthorizationOptions options,
                                         ILogger logger)
    {
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(AuthorizationPolicy)} Configuration started ...");
        var policies = FindPolicies();
        options.TryToAddPolicies(policies, logger);
        logger.LogInformation($"{nameof(AuthorizationPolicy)} Configuration completed.");
    }

    private static IEnumerable<PolicyInformation> FindPolicies()
    {
        var policyProvider = typeof(Policies);
        return from method in policyProvider.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
               // The method should configure the policy builder, not return a built policy.
               where method.ReturnType == typeof(void)
               let methodParameter = method.GetParameters()
               // The method has to accept the AuthorizationPolicyBuilder, and no other parameter.
               where methodParameter.Length == 1 && methodParameter[0].ParameterType == typeof(AuthorizationPolicyBuilder)
               select new PolicyInformation(method.Name, method);
    }

    private static void TryToAddPolicies(this AuthorizationOptions options,
                                         IEnumerable<PolicyInformation> policies,
                                         ILogger logger)
    {
        foreach (var policy in policies)
        {
            try
            {
                options.AddPolicy(policy.Name, builder => { policy.Method.Invoke(null, new object[] {builder}); });
                logger.LogInformation($"Policy '{policy.Name}' was configured successfully.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                options.AddPolicy(policy.Name, Policies.PolicyConfigurationFailedFallback);
                logger.LogCritical(e, $"Failed to configure policy '{policy.Name}'. Using fallback policy instead.");
            }
        }
    }

    private class PolicyInformation
    {
        internal string Name { get; }

        internal MethodInfo Method { get; }

        internal PolicyInformation(string name,
                                   MethodInfo method)
        {
            Name = name;
            Method = method;
        }
    }
}
```

The `PolicyConfigurationFailedFallback`-policy from step #1 will prevent access to your protected resources, while at the same time still providing a policy for your expected policy name. This way, you won't end up clustering your browser or Visual Studio console with "policy not found" messages.

Of cause, you can get rid of the logging at any time, if you want to.

## 3. Configure services in client and server

Utilizing the extension method, the `ConfigureServices` method in **both** `Startup` classes (**client and server**) shrinked down very:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /* ... */

    // For the server-side Startup class you can get the ILogger from the constructor instead.
    // For the client-side Startup class you have to get the ILogger here.
    var logger = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<ILogger<Startup>>();
    services.AddAuthorizationCore(options => options.AddSharedPolicies(logger));

    /* ... */
}
```

## 4. Using the policy in controllers

Straight-forward, and instead of defining yet another property that contains the name of your policy, you can simply use the `nameof()` operator to get the name of your policy:

```
[Authorize(nameof(Policies.TimeMustBeEvening))]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataController : Controller
{
   /* ... */
}
```

## 5. Using the policy in Blazor pages and components

Similiar to the way you apply the policies to your controllers, you can use the `nameof()` operator in your Blazor pages and components.

Either for the whole Blazor page:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policies.NameMustBeBlazorAdmin))]
```

Or for individual parts using the `AuthorizeView` component:

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="@nameof(Policies.NameMustBeBlazorAdmin)">
<th>Temp. (F)</th>
<th>Summary</th>
</AuthorizeView>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to use the Authentication and Authorization system built into the Blazor framework. See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/tree/master/src/Components/Components/src/Auth

You may use the  Component which supports policy-based authorization

**Samples: server-side or client-side Blazor**

```
<AuthorizeView Policy="content-editor">
    You can only see this if you satify the "content-editor" policy.
</AuthorizeView>
```

**Using the [Authorize] attribute**

```
@page "/"
@attribute [Authorize(Policy = "content-editor")]

You can only see this if you satisfy the 'content-editor' policy.
```

These two code snippets above are to satisfy your needs to `dynamically show or hide views or parts of views`

Of course you need to perform authorization checks on your server to protect API endpoints accessed by your client-side application

Look for more details and samples in the docs. This is an amazing system with which you can easily authenticate and authorize your users.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for your reply Isaac, but in my question I'm not asking about how to use the authorization in the `*.razor` files. I'm aware that I have to write `<AuthorizeView Policy="content-editor">`. I'm asking about the way the client knows about this policy - which, as far as I know, comes along with registering the authorization policies in the client, not the server. Which brings me to my actual question about the shared policy.

Comment: To be more specific, thanks to your link, how can the [`AuthorizationPolicyProvider` of the `AuthorizeViewCore`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Components/Components/src/Auth/AuthorizeViewCore.cs) in the client use the **same** policies as the server? While observing the dependency obstacles listed in my question.

Comment: I think you have to add services.AddAuthorizationCore(); in the Startup.ConfigureServices method of your client project.

Comment: Yeah, that's working as well, and no issue. I made an edit to the original question, pointing out what happens when you put everything into the shared project. IMHO, it's still a mess that the `IdentityConstants` are not available.